# How predefine templates for webform email templates?

Tags: webforms

I need to have a bunch of different webform e-mail templates with different text - how do I create those with code in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this sorted out, I used `hook_form_alter` to get the stuff into the select field, and did an override on the javascript-file from the webform module. I will try to answer it more complety in the next days if I have the time to do so.

Comment: Any info you can give on this would be great; we're trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Webform emails are themeable using `.tpl.php` files just as nodes, views etc. There is a *THEMING.txt* document that ships with Webform that explains exactly how to do what you are after, although the bit you're looking for is near the top:

> If you want to edit the e-mail sent by only one particular webform,
>   rename the file "webform-mail-[node id here].tpl.php", replacing [node
>   id here] with the node ID of the webform.

- [Webform 6.x-3.x](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/THEMING.txt)
- [Webform 7.x-3.x](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/THEMING.txt)
- [Webform 7.x-4.x](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-4.x:/THEMING.txt)

There's also this handbook page on Drupal.org: [Customising the emails sent by webform](https://drupal.org/node/1337488)

Comment: No, that is not my need - I want to have my own e-mail templates - like the default and custom one - not a tpl file, with predefined text.

Comment: Ah, so you want to add your own options to that list? E.g. Default, Custom, MiSc 1, MiSc 2?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to have.