# How to use the admin theme for webform email

Tags: webforms

I would like my html e-mails that are sent after a webform is submitted to use my admin theme. I tried using htmlmail module but that did not work.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before. You can use a webform email template.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/82501/3279

For the template file you should be able to override the theme assigned to the template by trying one of the many approaches outlined on this page:

[Force a page to be rendered in admin theme (overlay mode)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18183/force-a-page-to-be-rendered-in-admin-theme-overlay-mode)